# Sqlfiddle con tablas de esquema HR de ejemplo de SGBD Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlfiddle

En el sitio [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) quisiera alguna manera de cargar rápidamente todas las tablas del esquema de ejemplo `HR` que se usa en el sistema gestor de base de datos `Oracle`, o en su defecto, cambiarme al esquema `HR`.

¿Existe algún [sqlfiddle](/questions/tagged/sqlfiddle) que ya lo tenga precargado?

Esencialmente me interesan las tablas employees, departments y jobs.

Answer (score 3):

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) es un sitio muy básico para probar diferentes tipos de consultas en varios RDBMS, no tiene precargado ningún esquema ni nada que se le parezca de ninguna plataforma, esto lo tienes que hacer tú como usuario.

Para ello tienes una opción muy útil en la parte superior "Text to DDL" que convierte tablas a sentecias DDL y añade los CREATE e INSERT necesarios. Repites la operación para las tablas que tengas con un set de datos adecuado y ya estarás listo para hacer las consultas que necesites.

A raíz de tú comentario, aquí tienes, una imagen vale más que mil palabras. Asegúrate que el copia+pega que haces de tu entorno tengas las cabeceras de las columnas porque sino fallará. Yo uso SQL Server así que la captura es del SMSS, tú quizás uses Toad u otro entorno para Oracle. Tienes la opción antes de crear las sentencias DDL de probar a parsear el texto, si hay algún fallo te lo dice y lo podrás corregir. A veces tienes que liarte un poco quitando un espacio aquí y allá o cosas así, depende de como te venga la tabla.

Aquí tienes [un enlace a como ha quedado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c2dc/1/0), con una SELECT básica y el resultado

[image: ejemplo como crear esquema en SQLFIDDLE]

Comment: Eso suena genial, ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de como se usa el text to ddl? porque con sql apenas y logro crear un pedazo de la tabla employees

Comment: wooow me parece genial... lo pruebo el lunes, pero de momento... +1 muchas gracias :)